# Fetch multiple types of entities From CosmosDb in a single query

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to get all the types of entities from a Collection in CosmosDb using the sql API. But I get only the `BaseClass` entities instead of the specific class entities.

Here are my models:

```
public class ActivityBase: { // common properties for all activities... }
public class Running: ActivityBase { // specific properties to Running... }
public class Dancing: ActivityBase { // specific properties to Dancing... }
```

Here is the current query:

```
 var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ActivityBase>(collection.SelfLink, feedOptions)
                .Where(/*some filter which does not exclude entities by ActivityType*/) 
                .AsDocumentQuery();
```

What I end up with is a `List<ActivityBase>`.

What I need is a `List<ActivityBase>` which contains specific entities like `Running`, `Dancing` and not just the base class objects. Is there a way to specify this in the query itself?

Answer (score 0):

The `T` type in the `CreateDocumentQuery` just tells the SDK where to map the objects retrieved, not what objects to query for. That part goes in the filter.

If your filter isn't narrowing down the query to the `Running` and `Dancing` types then all this query will do is retrieve any type of object and then map it to the `ActivityBase`. This means that even if you are querying for the right types, you will never see them because the mapper will ignore them.

You can quickly check that by changing the `T` type to `dynamic` or `Document` and checking the content.

Comment: I agree and know that. My filter does not exclude by the type of the activity (updated the question). I have tried the `dynamic` way but then for every object I will have to try and cast to every activity, which doesn't sound very well. Is there an out of the box way to do this?

Comment: No, with this SDK there isn't. You will need either one query per type or some flag indicating what this item is to make remapping easier.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  How can you return `ActivityBase` and expect it to have specific properties for `Running` if the base class doesn't have them?

You will have to return a dynamic or create a container object like this to return

```
public class ActivitiesResponse {
   public List<Running> RunningActivities { get; set; } = new List<Running>();
   public List<Dancing> DancingActivities { get; set; } = new List<Dancing>();
}
```

Then query it with `dynamic`

In CosmosDB make sure you add Type to both object types so you know what object you got back:

```
public class Running {
  public string Type {get; set;} = nameof(Running);
  // other properties
}
public class Dancing {
  public string Type {get; set;} = nameof(Dancing);
  // other properties
}
```

Now query as dynamic and then based on the Type deserialize to appropriate object and return the `ActivitiesResponse` which contains both types.

```
var iterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<dynamic>()
    .Where(p => /* some query */)
    .ToFeedIterator();

var result = new ActivitiesResponse();

while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
    
    foreach(var item in response){ 
        if(item.Type == nameof(Running)){
          var runningActivity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Running>(item.ToString());
          result.RunningActivities.Add(runningActivity);
        }
        else if(item.Type == nameof(Dancing)){
          var dancingActivity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dancing>(item.ToString());
          result.DancingActivities.Add(dancingActivity);
        }
    }    
}

return result;
```